# The trait bound `(): futures::Future` is not satisfied when using TcpConnectionNew

Tags: tcp, rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to write a simple TCP client in Rust using [Tokio](https://tokio.rs/) crate. My code is pretty close to [this example](https://tokio.rs/docs/getting-started/tls/) minus the TLS:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate tokio_io;

use futures::Future;
use tokio_core::net::TcpStream;
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;
use tokio_io::io;

fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();

    let connection = TcpStream::connect(&"127.0.0.1:8080".parse().unwrap(), &handle);

    let server = connection.and_then(|stream| {
        io::write_all(stream, b"hello");
    });

    core.run(server).unwrap();
}
```

However, compilation fails with the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(): futures::Future` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:16:29
   |
16 |     let server = connection.and_then(|stream| {
   |                             ^^^^^^^^ the trait `futures::Future` is not implemented for `()`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::IntoFuture` for `()`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `(): futures::Future` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:20:10
   |
20 |     core.run(server).unwrap();
   |          ^^^ the trait `futures::Future` is not implemented for `()`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::IntoFuture` for `()`
```

I find it strange because according to [the documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio-core/0.1.10/tokio_core/net/struct.TcpStreamNew.html) it should be implemented.

I'm using

- Rust 1.19.0
- futures 0.1.16
- tokio-core 0.1.10
- tokio-io 0.1.3

What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TL;DR: remove the semicolon after `io::write_all`.

---

Review the definition of [`and_then`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.16/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.and_then):

```
fn and_then<F, B>(self, f: F) -> AndThen<Self, B, F> 
where
    F: FnOnce(Self::Item) -> B,
    B: IntoFuture<Error = Self::Error>,
    Self: Sized,
```

The closure (`F`) has to return some type (`B`) that can be converted into a future (`B: IntoFuture`) with an error type that matches the starting closure (`Error = Self::Error`).

What does *your* closure return? `()`. Why is that? Because you've placed a semicolon (`;`) at the end of your line. `()` does not [implement the trait `IntoFuture`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/future/trait.IntoFuture.html#implementors), which is indicated by the error message part "on the impl of `futures::IntoFuture` for `()`":

```
impl<F: Future> IntoFuture for F {
    type Future = F;
    type Item = F::Item;
    type Error = F::Error;
}
```

Removing the semicolon will cause the `Future` returned by `io::write_all` to be returned back to `and_then` and the program will compile.

In general, futures work by combining together smaller components which are themselves futures. All of this works together to build a single large future which is essentially a state machine. It's good to keep this in mind, as you will almost always need to return a future when using such combinators.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately the answer here is quite specific, but the question turns up for any kind of search for:

> the trait `futures::Future` is not implemented for `()`

A typical scenario for this kind of error is:

```
foo.then(|stream| {
    // ... Do random things here
    final_statement();
});
```

This causes an error because the majority of the [extension functions](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.0-alpha/futures/trait.FutureExt.html) require the return type to implement `IntoFuture`. However, `()` does not implement `IntoFuture`, and by terminating the block with a `;` the implicit return type is `()`.

However, `IntoFuture` *is* implemented for [`Option` and `Result`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.0-alpha/futures/trait.IntoFuture.html#foreign-impls).

Rather than just randomly removing semicolons vaguely in the hope this will somehow magically make your code compile, consider:

You should be returning something that can be converted into a `Future` using `IntoFuture`.

If you don't have a specific promise that you're returning, consider returning `Ok(())` to say simply 'this is done' from your callback:

```
foo.then(|stream| {
    // ... Do random things here
    final_statement();
    return Ok(()); // <-- Result(()) implements `IntoFuture`.
});
```

Note specifically I terminate this block with an explicit return statement; this is deliberate. This is a typical example of how the ergonomics of 'can omit semicolon to implicitly return object' is tangibly harmful; terminating the block with `Ok(());` will continue to fail with the same error.