# Cannot use Stream::take_while on an mpsc::channel: bool: Future is not satisfied

Tags: rust, future, rust-tokio

I want to run an event loop in one thread and handle data from a UDP socket until another thread signals to stop work.

This is a difficult task for me, so I want to start from a simpler task:
one thread starting the event loop and waiting for another thread to signal the end:

```
use futures::{future, future::Future, stream::Stream, sync::mpsc};
use std::{io, io::BufRead, thread};

fn main() {
    let (mut tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<bool>(1);

    let thr = thread::spawn(|| {
        let mut runtime = tokio::runtime::current_thread::Runtime::new().unwrap();
        runtime.spawn(
            future::lazy(|| {
                println!("event loop started");
                Ok(())
            })
            .and_then(rx.take_while(|x| *x == true).into_future()),
        );

        runtime.run()
    });

    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        println!("{}", line);
        if line == "exit" {
            tx.try_send(false).unwrap();
            break;
        }
    }
    thr.join().unwrap().unwrap();
}
```

This code doesn't compile:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `bool: futures::future::Future` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:14:26
   |
14 |             .and_then(rx.take_while(|x| *x == true).into_future()),
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `futures::future::Future` is not implemented for `bool`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::future::IntoFuture` for `bool`

error[E0599]: no method named `into_future` found for type `futures::stream::take_while::TakeWhile<futures::sync::mpsc::Receiver<bool>, [closure@src/main.rs:14:37: 14:51], bool>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:14:53
   |
14 |             .and_then(rx.take_while(|x| *x == true).into_future()),
   |                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `into_future` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `futures::stream::take_while::TakeWhile<futures::sync::mpsc::Receiver<bool>, [closure@src/main.rs:14:37: 14:51], bool> : futures::stream::Stream`
           `&mut futures::stream::take_while::TakeWhile<futures::sync::mpsc::Receiver<bool>, [closure@src/main.rs:14:37: 14:51], bool> : futures::stream::Stream`
```

How do I fix the compilation error?

Answer (score 0):

Read and understand the documentation and function signature of methods you attempt to use:

```
fn take_while<P, R>(self, pred: P) -> TakeWhile<Self, P, R>
where
    P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> R,
    R: IntoFuture<Item = bool, Error = Self::Error>,
    Self: Sized,
```

`take_while` takes a closure that returns some type that must be convertible into a future; a `bool` is not convertible into a future. The simplest way to do this is via [`future::ok`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/future/fn.ok.html):

```
let thr = thread::spawn(|| {
    let mut runtime = tokio::runtime::current_thread::Runtime::new().unwrap();
    runtime.spawn({
        rx.take_while(|&x| future::ok(x))
            .for_each(|x| {
                println!("{}", x);
                future::ok(())
            })
    });

    runtime.run()
});
```

See also:

- [The trait bound `(): futures::Future` is not satisfied when using TcpConnectionNew](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46625376/155423)

> But my problem also in joining `future::lazy` and `rx.take_while`

That's an unrelated problem to what you asked about. Again, we look at the docs, this time for [`Future::and_then`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.23/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.and_then):

```
fn and_then<F, B>(self, f: F) -> AndThen<Self, B, F>
where
    F: FnOnce(Self::Item) -> B,
    B: IntoFuture<Error = Self::Error>,
    Self: Sized,
```

Similarly to `take_while`, it takes a closure and the closure must return something that can be convertible into a future. Your code doesn't provide a closure.

Then look at [`Stream::into_future`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.23/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.into_future). This returns [a type that implements `Future`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.23/futures/stream/struct.StreamFuture.html#impl-Future) and returns a tuple. The first item in the tuple is a single value from the stream, the second is the stream itself, to allow getting more values.

To get all the item and error types correct, I've make liberal use of `map(drop)` and `map_err(drop)` — you will want to do something better for your data and error handling.

```
runtime.spawn({
    future::lazy(|| {
        println!("event loop started");
        Ok(())
    })
    .and_then(|_| {
        rx.take_while(|&x| future::ok(x))
            .into_future()
            .map(drop)
            .map_err(drop)
    })
    .map(drop)
});
```

---

Really, you should just use a [oneshot channel](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.23/futures/sync/oneshot/index.html); it's much simpler:

```
use futures::{
    future::{self, Future},
    sync::oneshot,
};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = oneshot::channel();

    let thr = thread::spawn(|| {
        let mut runtime = tokio::runtime::current_thread::Runtime::new().unwrap();

        runtime.spawn({
            future::lazy(|| {
                println!("event loop started");
                Ok(())
            })
            .and_then(|_| rx.map_err(drop))
        });

        runtime.run()
    });

    let lines = ["hello", "goodbye", "exit"];
    for &line in &lines {
        if line == "exit" {
            tx.send(()).unwrap();
            break;
        }
    }

    thr.join().unwrap().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: As an alternative to avoid for_each : `rx.take_while(|x| futures::future::ok(*x == true)).into_future().then(|_| Ok(())) ` works also .

Comment: But my problem also in joining `future::lazy` and `rx.take_while`

Comment: @user1244932 updated.

Comment: @ÖmerErden please don't feel like you need to delete your answer if it's still correct; you recognized that the OP wanted the chaining and `into_future` before I did. It's always possible that the OP thinks that your answer better fits their code.